# Error calculating CSS selector specificity with pseudo-classes

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class, css-specificity

I'm reading a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance) on MDN, and I encountered the following snippet:

```
/* weight: 0015 */
div div li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

My question is: Why this rule's specificity is 0015, rather than 0024?

I think the overall selector contains 2 pseudo-classes selectors(`:nth-child(2)` and `:hover`) and 4 element selectors(`div`, `div`, `li` and `a`), so its specificity should be 0024.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't. The example had an error in it but [has now been fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance$compare?locale=en-US&to=1102087&from=1078002).